# MATLABs double arithmetic

Tags: matlab, error-estimation, computer-arithmetic

this is a classical problem, but I need help to pinpoint what I am missing.

Problem:
In MATLAB

(exp(1) + 10^12) - 10^12

gives you a double which equal to e, up to 5 correct digits. But I thought it would be 4.

One has exp(1) + 10^12 = 1.000000000002718e+12, where 1.000000000002718 contains 16 digits, the precision we are working at. All that is left of e is 2.718, but (exp(1) + 10^12) - 10^12 = 2.7182 (I have left out the digits following the last decimal 2), meaning I have one more digit saved.

Question:
Where or how is the extra digit stored? I know that the last the 53 bit for unsigned 64 bit IEEE is used for rounding, is it related to my question?

Comment: Note that "[...] contains 16 digits, the precision we are working at" is incorrect. The number is stored in *bits*, and the decimal representation of those bits can require more than 16 digits. For example, 001 represents 0.25, so that 3 bits correspond to 3 decimals.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no such thing as an "unsigned 64 bit IEEE". Floating point numbers are always signed, in IEEE standard formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dec2bin(typecast((exp(1) + 1e12) - 1e12, 'uint64'))` to obtain the binary representation of the double precision floating point.

> 100000000000101101111110000101010001011000101000101100000000000
>   100001001101101000110101001010010100010000000000101100000000000
>   100000000000101101111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>   100000000000101101111100111011011001000101101000011100000000000
>   100000000000101101111101101111110100100001111111110010000000000

are the binary representations of

- e
- e + 1e12
- (e + 1e12) - 1e12
- 2.718
- 2.7182

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I can't guarantee it, but I suspect that matlab will return a signed double rather than an unsigned, so you've probably only got 52 bits to play with.

However to actually address the question, consider a clock that has stopped with the hour hand on 1 o'clock. It has a terrible precision, but if you look at it at 12.30, it's accurate to within half an hour. Similarly, the $(1/2)^{52}$ step in the representation of doubles is only useful to tell us the **maximum** truncation error in the representation of mathematics, the actual accuracy can be far better.

As a concrete example of something closer to the bound, compare your example with the result of  $(\pi+10^{12})-10^{12}$.